# Get ag-grid page which is clicked

Tags: pagination, ag-grid

In ag-grid pagination, I need catch the page where I am clicking. I do not want the current page, this is the origin, I need the destiny.

For instance:

Pagination: <<  < Page 4 of 15 > >>

When click << the result must be 1.
When click < the result must be 3.
_
When click > the result must be 5.
When click >> the result must be 15.

```
paginationChanged(params) {
    // Something like:
    // params.paginationGetCurrentPage();
},
```

Comment: Please subscibre more details. To full understand you and after I can help you.

Comment: It is done, is it more clear?

Comment: This is only possible by implementing custom pagination controls. Here's how you can implement it in ag-grid - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/#custom-pagination-controls